# Flutter Native SDK Implementation

Tags: swift, flutter, kotlin

Guys, I am trying to create a package like this one https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_uxcam/changelog I have done native implementation to capture screenshot of the current activity and it's working perfectly in native Android and IOS I also implemented it with react native it working properly with react native but when I implemented it for flutter so every time I am getting black screen could you please help me out this issue

I tried implementing binding but it is not working in my case

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.